# Cantonese song 不可一世 - what is the spoken part at 2:02?

Tags: cantonese, songs

In the song 不可一世 (bat ho yat see) by Hong Kong band Beyond, there is some spoken Cantonese at around 2 minutes which I can't make out. It's spoken in a deep voice, and some others (presumably the band members) shout a reply. What are they saying?

If it's not off topic I'm also curious about the context of the song. I understand that 不可一世 means extremely, insufferably arrogant. Who are they referring to that is so arrogant and why don't they need him anymore?

[Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gm6Rd5DcbsE)

lyrics:

```
誰願壓抑心中怒憤衝動
咒罵這虛與偽與假

從沒信要屈膝面對生命　縱沒有別人幫
一生只靠我雙手　讓我放聲瘋狂叫嚷

*今天的他　呼風可改雨　不可一世太囂張
乜哥乜哥　多麼的討厭
We don't need you anymore ,
go to hell

誰願意將一生扮作英雄
去面對風雨共創傷

難道世間真的沒有公道　縱沒有別人可
高聲呼叫我不甘　獨我放聲瘋狂叫嚷
今天的他　呼風可改雨　不可一世太囂張
乜哥乜哥　多麼的討厭
We don't need you anymore ,
go to hell

今天的他　呼風可改雨　不可一世太囂張
乜哥乜哥　多麼的討厭
We don't need you anymore ,
今天的他　呼風可改雨　不可一世太囂張
乜哥乜哥　多麼的討厭
We don't need you anymore ,
go to hell
今天的他　呼風可改雨…
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

「點呀？又有邊個覺得唔滿意呀？」(in Mandarin: 什麼? 又有誰覺得不滿意了？) = "What? Who else feel dissatisfied?"

「我地呀！」(我們啊) = "We do!"

乜哥乜哥 (some big shot) is the one being arrogant

In Hong Kong, people often nickname a government department head 「一哥」, e.g. 「警隊一哥」 means Head of the police department.

Since this song is dated. I don't know who they were specifically referring to, Most likely someone in power at that time

**Edit**:

> [「不可一世」歌曲创作背景](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E4%B8%8D%E5%8F%AF%E4%B8%80%E4%B8%96/3701653#1) (background of the creation of the song "Insufferably Arrogant")
>
> Beyond在香港成名后前经理**陈健添**就更加变本加厉的密密麻麻安排商业娱乐性重的工作，陈健添还因经理人佣金和分红和Beyond起纠纷，Beyond早已厌倦陈健添这种为利是图处处算计的人压榨逼迫, 以及他安排下过的违背意愿的奉迎生活，他们写的《不可一世》是讽刺逼迫控制他们越紧的经理人陈健添，而不是陈健添口中所说的讽刺电视台高层。所以，Beyond就决定在1991年12月尾合约结束时就不再与陈健添续约。

So, The Beyond were dissatisfied with their manager 陈健添  who pushed them very hard toward the commercial and entertainment side of the business at the time (*I suppose they felt they were more artists than showmen*) . They wrote this song to satirize him, eventually they parted way with him after the end of their contract

Comment: It was quite a petty reason to write a song for it. 君子絕交不出惡言，大丈夫合則來不合則去. This action of Beyond was not gentlemanly or manly. BTW, their lyrics writing skill was very poor compare to real talents like Sam Hui and 黃霑

Comment: I see, thanks @Tang Ho. Makes sense now: "We don't need you any more! Go to hell!"